# Does compiling with -g, in itself, degrade performance?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, debug-information

(This is a question about gcc and clang, but might apply to other compilers.)

If I compile my C or C++ code, and generate debug info using the `-g` switch, does this in itself degrade performance of the compiled program in any way...

1. With minimum optimization (`-O0`)?
2. With maximum optimization (`-O3`)?

**Note:** I don't mean the performance penalty of having to parse/load the executable, which is larger due to the extra content; I mean the code that's run.

Comment: Compare a program compiled with `-g` and the same program compiled without `-g`. You should see no difference in the actual generated code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The fact that I don't see a difference in the code generated for a specific program does not necessarily mean there's never any difference...

Comment: Strictly seen: Yes, at least when you keep the debugging symbols within the executable, because that means there's more to load (or skip over during loading). This is IMO negligible in practice, though.

Comment: @DanielJour: Yeah, ok, fair point, but it's not what I meant. Added a note to clarify.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, -O3 will degrade the value of the debug information, not the other way around.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I do not think there is any performance difference. Indeed the generated code would be the same and `-g` is usable with `-O` according to the documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html). Besides, debugging symbols aren't written into the code but into another section called "debug section" which isn't even loaded at runtime (only by a debugger)

`-g` will not change what optimizations are run, or code generated.
This is gcc policy as stated [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2005-03/msg00034.html)

However it might be useful to note that the same documentation states that:

> The shortcuts taken by optimized code may occasionally be surprising:
>   some variables you declared may not exist at all; flow of control may
>   briefly move where you did not expect it; some statements may not be
>   executed because they compute constant results or their values are
>   already at hand; some statements may execute in different places
>   because they have been moved out of loops. Nevertheless it is possible
>   to debug optimized output. This makes it reasonable to use the
>   optimizer for programs that might have bugs.

So in the end the debugging will never hurt your optimisation but the opposite is false and using `-O3` might degrade your debugging information (by deleting useless variables for instance).

Note that it may be better in that case to use `-Og` (as stated [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-Og-737)) since it will:

> Optimize debugging experience. -Og enables optimizations that do not
>   interfere with debugging. It should be the optimization level of
>   choice for the standard edit-compile-debug cycle, offering a
>   reasonable level of optimization while maintaining fast compilation
>   and a good debugging experience.

However this would impact performance because some optimisation passes that would interfere with the debugging would not be done.

---

*Edit:*

The links and quotes answer your question for `gcc`.It might not apply to other compilers such as `clang`.
However I have found some documentation as well for `clang`.
For instance [here](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html#id10):

> Basically, the debug information allows you to compile a program with
>   “-O0 -g” and get full debug information, allowing you to arbitrarily
>   modify the program as it executes from a debugger. Compiling a program
>   with “-O3 -g” gives you full debug information that is always
>   available and accurate for reading (e.g., you get accurate stack
>   traces despite tail call elimination and inlining), but you might lose
>   the ability to modify the program and call functions where were
>   optimized out of the program, or inlined away completely.

Comment: @einpoklum it was just a reminder. But I suppose the beginning answers your questions. It was just additional information as you may know it but others may not. I saw that you removed your comments, any reasons for that? I think I did answer your question here

Answer (score 4):

The -g flag adds debugging information to the binary. This exists in a separate section (`.stab` and `.stabstr`) of the executable from the `.text` CPU run bit. When run outside the debugger, the debug section is not loaded by the operating system loader. The debug info can also easily be stripped out using the `strip` utility to generate binaries that are identical to one compiled without the -g flag.

Normally however when you want to debug stuff you will compiled without optimizations and the NDEBUG preprocessor macro. However these things are not controlled by the -g flag.

Answer (score 1):

There wont be any performance hit if you run it outside a debugger. The debug symbols are to aid the debugging. The generated code shall be the same in both the cases.

Comment: Post something to support your opinion.